# Force Android users to visit websites with Google Chrome or Safari

Tags: android, google-chrome, safari, user-agent

We made a webapp optimized for Google Chrome/Safari. I'd like to

- force all Android users to use Google Chrome to visit the website. If Chrome isn't available I don't want their visit the website.
- force all iOS users to use Safari

Can you suggest to me the right way to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a simple solution for you.

First you need to check what browser they are using, and then you need to direct them to either chrome or safari if they are not using one of those 2 browsers that you guys optimized for.

So:

```
// Opera 8.0+
var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

// Firefox 1.0+
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

// Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && safari.pushNotification));

// Internet Explorer 6-11
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

// Edge 20+
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

// Chrome 1 - 71
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || 
!!window.chrome.runtime);

// Blink engine detection
var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;
```

The code above will assign boolean values of true if they are on that browser and false if they are not.

Now you can decide what to do now that you know what browser they are using

```
// If they are not on chrome and safari
if (!isChrome && !isSafari) {
    // replace this with whatever you want to do
    // in this case I make your website text red, but you could display a link 
    // to chrome app in playstore or whatever you need
    document.getElementByTagName("body").style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: Well thank you, but I haven't an Android app, just a web app :)

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the confusion haha. Can I ask what you are using to build your web app? HTML and JS?

Comment: Right, just html + js

Comment: Check my solution! I updated it for you! Let me know if it work, cheers!

Comment: @Premier Have you got a chance to try out my new solution?